# Rating bar with custom drawable not showing half star only full stars

Tags: android, ratingbar

Hello I have a rating bar with custom drawable but it only displays full stars only and not showing half
here is my code, how can I solve this?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"

    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"

    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"

    android:drawable="@drawable/filled_star" />
```

```
<style name="doctor_rating" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:minHeight">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">65dp</item>
    <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_rating_stars</item>
    <item name="android:stepSize">.1</item>
</style>


     
                    <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/doctor_rating_bar"
                    style="@style/doctor_rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:rating="3.5"
                    />
```

Comment: Share your Rating bar java code too

Comment: i added the code

Comment: Correct this:name="android:stepSize">0.1</item>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="doctor_rating" parent="android.widget.RatingBar">
<item name="android:minHeight">13dp</item>
<item name="android:minWidth">65dp</item>
<item name="android:numStars">5</item>
<item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_rating_stars</item>
<item name="android:stepSize">0.1</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below code this will help you.

custom_rating_stars.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ratingbar_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

ratingbar_empty.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_grey_small" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_grey_small" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_grey_small" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_grey_small" />

</selector>
```

ratingbar_filled.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" />

    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" />

    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/star_yellow" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just put this here as maybe it'll be useful to someone else. I had to change:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondaryProgress"

    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />
```

to

```
<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"

    android:drawable="@drawable/empty_star" />
```